# Disable button when lower then 0, enable when higher

Tags: jquery

I have a div with a value in it which is **`0`** standard.
I have two buttons, **`+`** and **`-`**

When the value is **`0`** I want my **`-`** button to be disabled and from the moment it is higher then **`0`** I want it enabled.

```
if (number == 0) {
    $("#min").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#plus").click(function () {
     number = number + 1;
     document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = number;
    });
}

if (number > 0) {
    $("#min").prop("disabled", false);

    $("#plus").click(function () {
     number = number + 1;
     document.getElementById('ptn1').innerHTML = number;
    });

    $("#min").click(function () {
     number = number - 1;
     document.getElementById('ptn1').innerHTML = number;
    });
}
```

Comment: You don't want to assign the event listeners inside an `if()`

Comment: @AlivetoDie done, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in your code so that you can get it easily(elaborated through comments too)-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#min").prop("disabled", true); // initially minus is disabled
    $("#plus").click(function () { // on click of + button
      $('#num').html(parseInt($('#num').html())+1);  // get div number, add 1 and paste again to the div(new number)
      if(parseInt($('#num').html())>0){ //if new value is greater than 0
        $("#min").prop("disabled", false); // enable - button
      }else{
        $("#min").prop("disabled", true); // otherwise remain disable
      }
  });

  $("#min").click(function () { // on click of - button
    $('#num').html(parseInt($('#num').html())-1); // get div number,substract 1 and again paste again to the div(new number)
      if(parseInt($('#num').html())>0){ // if the new number is >0
        $("#min").prop("disabled", false); // remain enable of - button
      }else{
        $("#min").prop("disabled", true); // otherwise disable - button
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="num">0</div><br/>

<input type="button" id="plus" value="+(Add)">
<input type="button" id="min" value="-(Subtrat)">
```

Note: Don't mix JavaScript  syntax and jQuery syntax together. Use either-one purely.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on('click', '#plus', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var value = parseInt($('#num').val());
   $('#num').val(value + 1);

   if ($("#min").is(':disabled')) {
     $("#min").prop("disabled", false);
   }
});

$(document).on('click', '#min', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var value = parseInt($('#num').val());
    $('#num').val(value - 1);

    if ((value - 1) == 0) {
        $("#min").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="num" value="0" />
<button id="min" disabled="">-</button>
<button id="plus">+</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This does exactly what you are asking for. It is fairly straight forward but feel free to ask for clarification

```js
//Set initial values
var divValue = 0;
$('.container').html(divValue);
$(".minusButton").prop("disabled", true);

//Do the magic
$(document).on("click", "button", function(e) {
  
  //This is the name of the button (uses the data attribute)
  var inputButton = $(this).data("change");
  
  //If the button is 'plus' increment else decrement
  if (inputButton === "plus") {
    divValue = divValue + 1;
  } else {
    divValue = divValue - 1;
  }
  
  //Output the value to the div
  $('.container').html(divValue);
  
  //Disable the minus button is the div value is less than 1
  if (divValue > 0) {
    $(".minusButton").prop("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $(".minusButton").prop("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class='minusButton button' data-change='minus'>-</button>
<button type="button" class='plusButton button' data-change='plus'>+</button>
<br>
<div class='container'></div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Completely different approach using custom events:

Note that you can use `number` itself as boolean for `disabled`

```js
var number = 2;

$("#min").on("update", function() {
  $(this).prop('disabled', !number);
}).trigger('update');

$('#ptn1').on('update', function() {
  $(this).text(number)
}).trigger('update');

$("#plus, #min").click(function() {
  var modifier = $(this).is('#plus') ? 1 : -1;
  number += modifier;
  $('#min, #ptn1').trigger('update');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="plus">+</button>
<button id="min">-</button>
<div id="ptn1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, it could be done like this:

- Give both buttons same className, the "minus" button is `disabled` by default because the default "value" of the `#theDiv` field is **`0`**.
- Upon a click of any of the two button, we pick the text of the `#theDiv` and **[`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** it.
- Depending on the value of the `id` attribute of the button, we use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to increase or decrease it.
- If the updated number is more than **`0`**, we enable the `#minus` button, else, it gets disabled.
- Finally we update the text of `#theDiv`.

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/91e1qo44/4/)

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  var input = $('#theDiv'),
    theVal = parseInt(input.text());

  theVal = ($(this).attr('id') == 'plus') ? theVal + 1 : theVal - 1;
  $('#minus').attr('disabled', (theVal <= 0)); // returns true if 0
  input.text(theVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="minus" class="btn" disabled>-</button>
<button id="plus" class="btn">+</button>
<div id="theDiv" style="display:inline-block;">0</div>
```